# Help someone in research paper in practical using my coding skills

Tags: research-process, thesis, literature-search, code

I'm a developer and I want to help someone in research and be a part of it by implementing it practical. Where I can find those people?

Comment: Welcome here. I think this question is slightly unfit for academia.SE. You could do so by being a freelance developer in some specific website.

Comment: While I do not think that your question is generally off-topic here, it is difficult to give you a helpful answer without further details. Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate: 1) What is your motivation to do this? 2) What exactly do you mean by *implementing it practical?* 3) Do you have a specific field of research in mind? 4) What is your prior experience with research or academia in general?